# slice "error using griddedInterpolant" in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to plot a slice diagram of soil volumetric data but I get this error trying to plot the slices (most of the error text comes from the hierarchy of my code as I execute the code through a Gui but the top is the most important problem):

```
Error using griddedInterpolant
The grid vectors do not define a grid of points that match the given values.

Error in interp3 (line 142)
            F = griddedInterpolant(X, Y, Z, V, method,extrap);

Error in slice (line 100)
    vi = interp3(x,y,z,v,xi,yi,zi,method);

Error in ANALYSE>Bouton3D_Callback (line 939)
slice(x,y,z,VOLUME_DATA,xslice,yslice,zslice,'nearest')

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 95)
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in ANALYSE (line 42)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in @(hObject,eventdata)ANALYSE('Bouton3D_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))


Error while evaluating UIControl Callback
```

And here is my code that's problematic (the line it points to is the last one):

```
function Bouton3D_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to Bouton3D (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
NB_LIGNES =str2num(get(handles.nb_lignes,'string'));
NB_COLONNES = str2num(get(handles.nb_colonnes,'string'));
SENSIBILITE_AMPLITUDE_SIGNAL =1;

TEMP = dir('L1/f1.csv');
FICHIER_SIGNAL_SPECTRAL= ['L1/',TEMP.name];
TABLEAU_SIGNAL_SPECTRAL = xlsread(FICHIER_SIGNAL_SPECTRAL);
NB_FREQ = size(TABLEAU_SIGNAL_SPECTRAL,1);

FREQUENCES = TABLEAU_SIGNAL_SPECTRAL(:,2);

VOLUME_DATA = zeros(NB_LIGNES,NB_COLONNES,NB_FREQ);



for L =1:NB_LIGNES
    for C =1:NB_COLONNES
        TEMP = dir(['L',num2str(L),'/f',num2str(C),'.csv']);
        FICHIER_SIGNAL_SPECTRAL= ['L',num2str(L),'/',TEMP.name];

        TABLEAU_SIGNAL_SPECTRAL = xlsread(FICHIER_SIGNAL_SPECTRAL);

        VOLUME_DATA(L,C,:)=(TABLEAU_SIGNAL_SPECTRAL(:,3)*SENSIBILITE_AMPLITUDE_SIGNAL); % En dB

    end
end

[x,y,z] = meshgrid(1:5,1:9,FREQUENCES);
xslice = 1; 
yslice = 1; 
zslice = 1:FREQUENCES(end)/5:FREQUENCES(end)-1;
slice(x,y,z,VOLUME_DATA,xslice,yslice,zslice,'nearest')
colormap hsv
```

Comment: What is the range of `FREQUENCES`? You assume it starts at 1, but does it? wouldn't be better `zslice =  FREQUENCES(1):FREQUENCES(end)/5:FREQUENCES(end);`? Why the `-1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and it seems to me that `VOLUME_DATA` has a wrong size. if I modify your code a little bit it throws no errors:

```
FREQUENCES = 1:6;
[x,y,z] = meshgrid(1:5,1:9,FREQUENCES);
VOLUME_DATA = x.*exp(-x.^2-y.^2-z.^2); % a function of x,y,z such that the output dimension fits the inputs dimensions 
xslice = 1;
yslice = 1;
zslice = 1:FREQUENCES(end)/5:FREQUENCES(end)-1;
slice(x,y,z,VOLUME_DATA,xslice,yslice,zslice,'nearest')
colormap hsv
```

or maybe try:

```
[x,y,z] = meshgrid(1:size(VOLUME_DATA,1),1:size(VOLUME_DATA,2),FREQUENCES);
```

Comment: Yes Thank you ! It made it work, It still dont exactly do what I want it to do, but I'll work on it a bit more